# SpringBoot refuse to start with idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I'm trying to swtch from Eclipse to IntelliJ Idea

My app is starting well with Eclipse, but I got an issue using Idea.

I'm figuring that something is wrong in my project, but Eclipse "tolerates" it.

I don't know where to start ?

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at fr.sgdbf.bus.service.ServiceApp.main(ServiceApp.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
... 13 common frames omitted
```

Edit : 
Here's the effective pom of the Spring app submodule

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
    <artifactId>bus-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
  <artifactId>bus-service</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>Bus Services module</name>
  <description>Bus Rest Entrypoints and request processing services</description>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
    <spring.boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring.integration.dsl.version>1.1.1.RELEASE</spring.integration.dsl.version>
    <spring.integration.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.integration.version>
    <spring.io.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.io.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-java-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-sftp</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.191</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-rest-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-zuora</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-tests</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-sf</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-scheduling</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
        <artifactId>bus-rules-engine</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>force-wsc</artifactId>
        <version>37.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
      <artifactId>bus-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
      <artifactId>bus-common</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
      <artifactId>bus-rest-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
      <artifactId>bus-scheduling</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
      <artifactId>bus-zuora</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>fr.test.bus</groupId>
      <artifactId>bus-sf</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>



  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <directory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target</directory>
    <finalName>bus-service-1.0.0</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>1.8</source>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>revision</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
              <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
              <generateGitPropertiesFilename>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/classes/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
              <format>properties</format>
              <gitDescribe>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <always>false</always>
                <abbrev>7</abbrev>
                <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
                <match>*</match>
                <forceLongFormat>false</forceLongFormat>
              </gitDescribe>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <verbose>true</verbose>
          <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
          <generateGitPropertiesFilename>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/classes/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
          <format>properties</format>
          <gitDescribe>
            <skip>false</skip>
            <always>false</always>
            <abbrev>7</abbrev>
            <dirty>-dirty</dirty>
            <match>*</match>
            <forceLongFormat>false</forceLongFormat>
          </gitDescribe>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-clean</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-testResources</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testResources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>resources</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>install</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-site</id>
            <phase>site</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>site</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>site-deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/site</outputDirectory>
              <reportPlugins>
                <reportPlugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                </reportPlugin>
              </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/site</outputDirectory>
          <reportPlugins>
            <reportPlugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            </reportPlugin>
          </reportPlugins>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>/home/marc/bus/bus-service/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Refresh the project assuming it is based on `Maven` or `Gradle`. Lets assume the app should download again some dependencies (probably not)

Comment: Already done a couple of times..

Comment: Can you share the `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Be sure, you are not using `apply plugin: 'eclipse'`

Comment: nice idea ! I see a org.eclipse.jetty in my libs, comes from one of my sub module which imports cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty. I'll try to deactivate it..

Comment: Add `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as a `provided` dependency. If that doesn't solve it add the `dependencies` section of your pom (or maybe even your full pom).

Comment: @M.Deinum I guess this is related to this IJ bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137364 which is also related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1194

Comment: I doubt that, due to the message that is being printed.

Comment: O indeed, thought I saw ClassNotFoundException but it complains about a missing bean.

Comment: I have several sub modules, it would be difficult to post all the poms.. if I post the effective pom of the sub module holding the spring boot app, would it be sufficient ?

Comment: @ObscurMoirage it looks like you're indeed missing `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as a provided dependency.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by g00glen00b, the tomcat dependency, marked as provided in my parent pom, was the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Idea is more strict for some reasons, since it's working with Eclipse